# How to pop up the youtube video player while hovering over the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am designing a website where I have a movie poster and as soon as the user hovers over the poster I want it to change to the YouTube video player (with the movie trailer).

I need the effect where the poster changes to the YouTube player. For linking the youtube video I am using iframe :

```
 <iframe width="420" height="345"
         src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
  </iframe>
```

Also when the video plays I want the background to go off and the video plays in the foreground, just like what is there in the http://www.imdb.com/.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I'd recommend is to use YouTube's iframe API as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

This way, you can only create the iframe on a basic JS event. In jQuery, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function{
  //load YouTube API as indicated above
  //set the id of each poster to the videoId of the trailer
  $('.someClass').mouseenter(this.id, loadPlayer); 
  var loadPlayer = function(id) {
    new YT.Player(id, {
    videoId: id,
    //other settings as needed
    }
  };
});
```

This is NOT a copy-paste job, so do some more research! This [post](http://www.skipser.com/p/2/p/youtube-video-embed-like-google-plus.html) (external blog, not mine) was super helpful for me to start learning on-demand video loading.

Comment: But that also doesn't satisfy the requirements. The video is not playing making the background page go dim. It works the same way as what iframe tag is doing.

Comment: I can't write all the code for you. That API documentation will tell you about play and pause events, autoplay, etc. As far as making the background "go dim," that's a separate issue.

You'll probably want to overlay a full-screen `<div>` with `opacity: 0.6` or so.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [mediaelementjs](http://mediaelementjs.com/examples/?name=youtube)  with youtube wrapper; 
it exposes yo uhtml5 methods and properties just like you would do with a   tag

Comment: But that also doesn't satisfy the requirements. The video is not playing making the background page go dim. It works the same way as what iframe tag is doing.

Comment: can you provide the code you tried?
I would place a transparent layer over the iFrame so that the hover event is corectly managed by your js, and then the  hide/show effect on the  relevant layer would make the thing work; have you done something like that? [because, of course, only using the library won't obtain you this effect]